# Multicast program lost data

Tags: c, multithreading, multicast

I've a multithread program written in C, one thread is receiving multicast data from the network and store it in a queue, another thread keep reading the queue and write it to file. Everything work just great i.e. no data lost from the multicast network.

Thread 1: Read Multicast data and store it into a queue
Thread 2: Read from queue and write it to file.

now I have another source of multicast data from network, I need another thread to read the network data, then I just go and add a for loop to create another thread for multicast data, then when the 2 multicast threads switching back and forth, I lost data from the multicast network!

Anyone has idea about why there are lost datagrams if 2 threads are used. Thanks

Comment: It depends, without any code that's hard to tell, esp because you are doing threaded code...

Comment: Yeah, we need code. At first glance this looks like a textbook lack of synchronisation problem around your queue, but unless we can see your queue implementation, we can't help any more.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely you are not using any concurrency mechanisms like semaphore or mutexs.  A classic solution is a monitor. A monitor provides a lock to mediate concurrent access and condition signals to allow independent processes blocking access (no busy waiting). In plain English this means that only one thread can access the data at a time. This prevents a reading thread from reading data that the writing thread has not yet finished writing. It also allows the reading threads to read data that the other reading thread has not yet read. An approach to implement this is to use a read-write mutex and an access semaphore. Each thread that wants to access the data decrements the access semaphore, the thread will either be granted access or sleep until it gets it turn. The read-write mutex will prevent a read thread from reading until some data has been written.

Comment: I've use mutex to avoid 2 threads to store data to the queue at the same time.

Comment: How many threads are accessing the same data? Is it three, one writer and two readers?